# Using Mockito: Argument(s) are different! Wanted: Actual invocation has different arguments:

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

When I run the JUnit test like this：

```
@Test
public void insertSignRewardTest() throws Exception{
    SignRewardRequest srr = new SignRewardRequest();
    srr.setBeginTime(new Date().toLocaleString());
    srr.setPoint(21);
    srr.setUseableId("123");
    srr.setEndTime(new Date().toLocaleString());

    SimpleDateFormat sFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    PointRewardDeploy pointRewardDepoly = new PointRewardDeploy();
     Date reward_begin_date = new Date();
     Date reward_end_date = new Date();
     reward_begin_date = sFormat.parse(srr.getBeginTime());
     reward_end_date = sFormat.parse(srr.getEndTime());
    pointRewardDepoly.setPoint_source_type(Long.valueOf(PointSourceType.SIGNED.getValue().toString()));
     pointRewardDepoly.setCreate_time(new Date());
     pointRewardDepoly.setUpdate_time(new Date());
     pointRewardDepoly.setReward_begin_date(reward_begin_date);
     pointRewardDepoly.setReward_end_date(reward_end_date);
     pointRewardDepoly.setStatus(1l);
     pointRewardDepoly.setReward_point(srr.getPoint());

    List<PointRewardDeploy> listPointRewardDeploy = new ArrayList<PointRewardDeploy>();
    listPointRewardDeploy.add(pointRewardDepoly);

    CommonListResult<PointRewardDeploy> cr = new CommonListResult<PointRewardDeploy>();
    cr.setCode("success");
    cr.setMsg("ok");
    cr.setSuccess(true);
    List<PointRewardDeploy> date = new ArrayList<>();
    date.add(pointRewardDepoly);
    cr.setData(date);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(srr);
    when(pointAccountService.savePointRewardDeploy(listPointRewardDeploy)).thenReturn(cr);

    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/sign/signPrizeDraw/insertSignReward")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(str))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());

    Assert.assertEquals(true, cr.getSuccess()); 
    verify(pointAccountService,times(1)).savePointRewardDeploy(refEq(listPointRewardDeploy));
}
```

I use the `org.mockito.Matchers.refEq` at:

```
verify(pointAccountService,times(1))
    .savePointRewardDeploy(listPointRewardDeploy) 

verify(pointAccountService,times(1))
    .savePointRewardDeploy(refEq(listPointRewardDeploy))
```

And then run it, it passed test but the print out message are null，like：

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
HTTP Method = POST
Request URI = /api/sign/signPrizeDraw/insertSignReward
Parameters = {}
Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
Handler:
Type = com.yirendai.mplatform.sign.controller.UserInfoListController
Method = public 
Async:
Async started = false
Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
Type = null

ModelAndView:
View name = null
View = null
Model = null

FlashMap:
Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
Status = 200
Error message = null
Headers = {}
Content type = null
Body = 
Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
Cookies = []
```

My question: is the print message right? I consider it not correct，but have no idea how to solve it. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Here's some general, if maybe unsolicited, feedback for you. To me, that test is too long. I consider a lot of setup in a test to be a code smell which suggests that responsibilities are not divided well. It's not easy to spot the test subject (or SUT) in your snippet--perhaps larger context (filename?) would help. I strive for test methods to be at most perhaps six or seven lines between "Arrange, Act, Assert". Much longer than that and I find that it's just too expensive to leave that way.

Answer (score 0):

The print output looks correct to me but it's difficult to be sure without seeing the controller method mapped to `/api/sign/signPrizeDraw/insertSignReward`, specifically: what is returned by that method.

If you are expecting the `body` to be included in the printed output then:

- The `body` is not printed in the request
- The `body` is only printed in the response if the reponse includes a `body`

Bear in mind that `print()` is not a formal output from the MVC layer, it's just a (sometimes) useful diagnostic tool. As long as you test ...

- Status code
- Response content and type (if the controller method returns something)
- Any side effects, in the form of verifications or expectations on layers below the controller (e.g. service or repository calls)

... then I think your MockMvc test case is sufficient and you won't need to concern yourself with the results of the `print()` output.